# Switching between UITextField cells in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Very beginner obj-c question.

I have grouped `TableView` with two sections http://uaimage.com/image/c6c9ca23 . In first section I have custom cells with `UITextField`'s in them. I need to implement Input Accessory View For keyboard with additional buttons "Next", "Prev" (to switch between text fields in first section) and "Done"(to dismiss the keyboard) http://uaimage.com/image/62f08045 .

Question is: what do I need to implement possibility to switch between text fields in cells in first section of TableView by tapping input Accessory buttons?
Do I need to tag cells or text fields and if so, how can I retrieve their value when user will tap on Input Accessory buttons? Or it is a better approach to do this?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume say u have 3 UITextField ie txt ,txt1, txt 2 with `tags` 0 1 and 2; Now add  `UITableViewCell *cell` in .h file.

**EDIT :**
Now to get references of all textField from current tableView cell add this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[textField superView];
    return YES;
}
```

Now in Input Accessory prev button action do this:

```
-(IBAction)previousBtn:(id)sender
{
   UITextField *txt = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:0];
   UITextField *txt1 = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
   UITextField *txt2 = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
   if(txt.isFirstResponder)
   {
    [txt resignFirstResponder];
    [txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   else if(txt1.isFirstResponder)
   {
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   else if(txt2.isFirstResponder)
   {
    [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt1 becomeFirstResponder];
   }
}
```

Now in Input Accessory next button action do this:

```
-(IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender
{
   UITextField *txt = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:0];
   UITextField *txt1 = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
   UITextField *txt2 = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:2];

   if(txt.isFirstResponder)
   {
    [txt resignFirstResponder];
    [txt1 becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   else if(txt1.isFirstResponder)
   {
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   else if(txt2.isFirstResponder)
   {
    [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt becomeFirstResponder];
   }
}
```

Comment: If I understand this code right, I need to write properties for all textfields programmatically?

Comment: no u need get reference all txt, txt1, txt2 from current UITableViewCell in tableView

Comment: I am sorry, one more question to code. cell is not declared anywhere except -cellForRowAtIndexPath: . Do I need to declare it (or to set properties) to use it in -textFieldShouldBeginEditing: ?